Type Error using ContentFul Node Module when trying to order results
I am using Contentful to manage content on a new site I am working on and it's going pretty well. However, I have an issue when trying to sort items. I am using NextJS14 and the Contentful node module. I have a model in Contentful that has a list of items, and one field name is "mark". I can load the data just fine, but if I try to sore by the marks field, I get a
Here is the code I am using to query the data:
await client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'reportingMarks',
            'fields.mark[match]': search,
            order: 'sys.contentType.sys.id,fields.mark',
            skip: skip,
            limit: limit
        }).then((response) => {
            setMarks(response.items);
            setTotalResults(response.total);
            setIsPending(false);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });

While this works on my local machine, when I try to build the project for deployment, I get the following message:

Type error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(OrderFilterPaths<EntrySys, "sys"> | "sys.contentType.sys.id" | "-sys.contentType.sys.id")[]'.

I have been searching for two days to find a way to make this work, but there isn't much help out there that I have seen. If anyone has any thoughts you could save my sanity!
I have read through the Contentful documentation and that has not been helpful. The documentation I found says this:

In order to order a result by a field, you need to specify order as a where selector. Please make sure, that you either just query for fields in sys, or specify a content type to look for.

My code specifies the content_type. I have also tried with "order" with just "fields.mark". Again, this works, but still causes the build error.

As usual, after posting my question I had a breaktrhough. My corrected code is:
await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'reportingMarks',
        'fields.mark[match]': search,
        order: ['sys.contentType.sys.id', 'fields.mark'],
        skip: skip,
        limit: limit

This works and passes for the build.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
